# How to correctly use an atomic type with condition_variable to avoid locking during relaxed atomic reads

Tags: c++11, atomic, condition-variable, memory-barriers, stdatomic

In the case of a shared counter that is waitable (with condition_variable) I wonder what is best regarding the count getter between using an atomic type for the count (mt_counter_B impl) or locking (mt_counter_A impl) ?
Also, are the memory_orders that I used correct ?
I intend to use the count_relaxed() for a stateless UI so I don't need it to be order-safe.

```cpp
class mt_counter_A
{
protected:
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex cv_m;
    uint64_t cnt;

public:
    mt_counter_A& operator++() {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
            ++cnt;
        }
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    uint64_t count() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        return cnt;
    }

    void wait_until(uint64_t count) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        cv.wait(lk, [&] { return cnt >= count; });
    }
};

class mt_counter_B
{
protected:
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex cv_m;
    std::atomic_uint_fast64_t cnt;

public:
    mt_counter_B& operator++() {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
            cnt.fetch_add(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        }
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    uint64_t count(std::memory_order order = std::memory_order_seq_cst) {
        return cnt.load(order);
    }

    uint64_t count_relaxed() {
        return cnt.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    void wait_until(uint64_t count) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        cv.wait(lk, [&]{ return cnt.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) >= count; });
    }
};
```

Comment: CV are not meant to be used w/o a lock.

Comment: I understand that, but concerning the synchronized value (here cnt), if it is a non-lock-free atomic type it would add an unnecessary layer of locking.. So if I want to access this value non safely but with atomicity, is it better to just use the lock coming with the condition_var usage or use an atomic + the memory_orders I proposed ?

Comment: What "safety" do you agree to drop? Also why do you want to use a CV in the first place?

Comment: I'd use a linked list of binary semaphores with custom wake up logic.

Comment: Lookup Windows' `PulseEvent` and why it's garbage and MS says you should never use it and why you can still use `SetEvent`. One will lose events sometimes the other won't. Now compare with CV: **a CV alone is fundamentally garbage like PulseEvent/WaitForSingleObject** and only the CV-mutex combo can be used reliably. Semaphores (incl. binary sem) have a stable state and are not subject to race conditions while pulse based primitives like CV are. There is no way to guarantee a thread is currently waiting and not about to wait on CV, except by combining it w/ a mutex. Design your own primitive!

Comment: Both approaches seems to be correct. "I wonder what is **best** regarding the count getter ..." - There is no *universal* "the best" in programming. Most likely, the best *performance* would be achieved by the approach B (read the counter without the mutex). But from the view of the **code maintaining**, approach A (which avoids atomic variables) could give much more than performance improvement in the function, which is called only from GUI thread: in that case the function is better to be fast, but it needn't to be *extremely* fast.